# Selenium 2 - Server HTTPS Problems

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having this strange(?) problem. When I run the selenium server (2.0rc3), after a little while, I can no longer connect to any HTTPS site without the certificate being flagged as invalid/untrusted.

Anyone else had this happen or know why?

EDIT: Any HTTPS url on any browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this (for now??) by running the selenium server on a different port

Comment: except tests in internet explorer don't work anymore. If anyone has some insight into why I would love to know

Comment: Looks like the computer needs to have CyberVillainsCA.ser installed if you want to use port 4444 (where IE works).

Answer (score 0):

copy the url and add it under trusted sites in the browser.

if you need this, ( this is IE8 path)
(on the browser Tools -> Internet Options -> Security Tab -> select Trusted site -> click Sites button -> paste the URL and click Add button )

Comment: my problem is that https url are not trusted anywhere in the system, any url with any browser. I feel like the server is messing with the system certificates

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the server with `-trustAllSSLCertificates`